# How to set the REMOTE value to my Secret in my Azure Function app Applications settings

Tags: azure, appsettings

I have a Seceret value that is the same name for my Test/Dev and prod environments. "localdbconnection". the value behind it is set to the test-db connection, dev-db connection, and prod-db connection. What I am not sure about is which do I put into the "Remote" value in my appsettings for my dbConnection of my local.settings.json.

Comment: What I am not sure about is which do I put into the "Remote" value in my appsettings for my dbConnection of my local.settings.json > the values of local.settings.json will not be included in function app after you deploy that trigger. local.settings.json is only used for local development. If you are developing a test function, Better add test-db-connection to the local.settings.json and while deploying the Function from Visual studio, Visual studio gives you the option to add the application settings before deployment.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am not sure about is which do I put into the "Remote" value in my appsettings for my dbConnection of my local.settings.json.

The values added in local.settings.json will not be included in Function app after you deploy that trigger in Azure function app.

As, The values in local.settings.json are gitignored during runtime, Refer below:-

[image]

As, You are running the code locally and the secret name is same, You can add the test-db-connection value to local.settings.json and test your function. You can also add all three values in your **local.settings.json** and test your function. Refer below:-

```json
{

"IsEncrypted": false,

"Values": {

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=strgaccount;AccountKey=xxxxxxJWvg/RB+8awH8Mhth7nA3ZB+hscZX0+AStciQ4xg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",

"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",

"test-db-connection" : "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:siliconserver.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=silicondb;UID=siliconuser;PWD=Password"

}

}
```

And call this connection in init.py by using the code below:-

```py
connectionstring  =  os.environ["test-db-connection"]
```

For all the three test, dev, prod use the settings below:-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccount;AccountKey=xxxxxBuZxxxxnxxxxg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "test-db-connection" : "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:siliconserver.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=Password",
    "dev-db connection" : "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:siliconserver.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=database;UID=Username;PWD=Password",
    "prod-db-connection" : "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:siliconserver.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=silicondb;UID=Username;PWD=Password"
  }
}
```

If you want to run a Function locally with values set for test, dev and prod settings.

You can add 3 of these settings in **local.settings.json**

```py
connectionstring = os.environ["test-db-connection"]

connectionstring2 = os.environ["dev-db connection"]

connectionstring3 = os.environ["prod-db connection"]
```

And use the specific connection strimng for carrying out specific tasks in your Database via Function Triggers.

As, The values you add in local.settings.json are not included to your Azure Function Settings in Configuration, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

- is not supported as the naming convention in Function Configuration settings, thus use either _ or . like above.
  test_db_connection VALUE

If you're using .Net Function you can set the app settings while deploying your Function app itself, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]